# Programmatically authenticate in Azure with MFA

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

From Python script I'd like to login to Azure account and check if I have assigned a given role in a given subscription.
The important thing is that the MFA is configured (with Authenticator app but also with TOTP codes).
I will have username, password and TOTP code in the script.
I found Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for Python but so far I don't see a way to use it in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not a supported scenario with MSAL, as MFA is meant as user interaction (not machine interaction).

I would recommend not using a personal account for this kind of activity but to use a Service Principal that has the permissions to view roles.

Comment: I don't have to use MSAL. I can even request OAuth server directly, but I'd like to know if it's possible. Unfortunately username, password and TOTP code are all I have and I'm not able to change it. The goal is to check if personal accounts have required permissions in automated way.